# Format git log output in PowerShell

Tags: git, powershell

I fetch my latest git log message via `$commitMessage = git log -1 --pretty=full 2>&1`. What confuses me is that `` $commitMessage.contains("`n") `` returns `False`, but there are clearly line breaks in `$commitMessage`.

How can I replace all linebreaks in `$commitMessage`?

Example content of `$commitMessage`:

```
commit ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949
Author: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 17 21:52:11 2008 -0700

    changed the version number
```

Thanks

Comment: `$commitMessage` is an array of strings, not a single multi-line string. You can concatenate them with the `-join` operator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's likely that `$commitMessage` is actually an array of strings. To find out, use the `.GetType()` method like so,

```
$commitMessage.GetType()
```

This will tell what kind of object you are working with. To join an array of strings, use the `-join` operator like so,

```
# A demo array of strings
$commitMessage = @()
$commitMessage += "commit ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949"
$commitMessage += "Author: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>"
$commitMessage += "Date:   Mon Mar 17 21:52:11 2008 -0700"
$commitMessage
commit ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949
Author: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 17 21:52:11 2008 -0700

# Join the cells with using arbitary separator
$commitMessage -join '|'
commit ca82a6dff817ec66f44342007202690a93763949|Author: Scott Chacon <schacon@gee-mail.com>|Date:   Mon Mar 17 21:52:11 2008 -0700
```